# cannot achieve this structure (custom posts VS categories VS ??)

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, customization

I'm a bit despaired because I cannot figure out how to do what I need (and I worked with WP since a lot of time ..)

Basically, I need to show my artistic work.
Each work is a post, or a page or a custom types (I still don't know which fits the best)
I have 3 categories of work and I won't have more.

I have a blog on my website and the custom permalink is:

> /blog/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/

So I guess it already removes the post type hypothesis (I don't want an url like :

**julienbayle.net/blog** ....

I want this:

**julienbayle.net/works** shows ALL my works as a portfolio page with only thumbnails as a grid/table and pagination.

**julienbayle.net/works/creation** shows only works in category creation as the grid of thumbnails too

**julienbayle.net/works/lab** shows only works in category lab as the grid of thumbnails too

**julienbayle.net/works/collab** shows only works in category collab as the grid of thumbnails too

When you click on thumbnails, you see the work considered, for instance:

**julienbayle.net/works/collab/work1**

**julienbayle.net/works/collab/work2**

etc.

I tried with a custom type named "works" but I had some problems with pagination.
So I tried by using basic category hierarchy and pages :

**works**

**-- creation**

**-- lab**

**-- collab**

But I cannot have the good permalink + the link to each work is wrong (contains the structure of a blog post)

Anyone here to help me?
BIG thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fairly straightforward with a custom post type and custom taxonomy.

First, [register a custom taxonomy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy) `worktype`, with rewrite parameter set to `works`:

```
'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'works' )
```

Next, [register a custom post type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) with rewrite set to `works/%worktype%`:

```
'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'works/%worktype%' )
```

You'll also need to set `with_front` to false if your posts have a static prefix, like `blog`.

Next, add a filter to `post_type_link` to swap the `%worktype%` tag with your selected worktype for individual works posts whenever WordPress outputs a link to an individual work:

```
function wpa_works_post_link( $post_link, $id = 0 ){
    $post = get_post($id);  
    if ( is_object( $post ) && $post->post_type == 'works' ){
        $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'worktype' );
        if( $terms ){
            return str_replace ( '%worktype%' , $terms[0]->slug , $post_link );
        }
    }
    return $post_link;
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'wpa_works_post_link', 1, 3 );
```

Comment: I was missing the last part about the rewrite.
It works very fine, thanks a lot Milo :)

Comment: something doesn't work.
strangely, I didn't verify to click on .. view work.

I cannot see any 'work'.. it gives a 404

Comment: set `has_archive` to `true` in your post type registration.

Comment: already did :-/

Comment: I created archive-works.php , archive-creation etc for each worktype in order to display global portfolio. It doesn't work :( (despaired)

Comment: I don't have to create archive-works according to http://codex.wordpress.org/images/1/18/Template_Hierarchy.png but taxonomy-worktype, taxonomy-worktype-lab, taxonomy-worktype-creation and my 3rd taxonomy-worktype-collaboration.

I'm okay for each template except taxonomy-worktype. I'm calling the page with julienbayle.net/works and it grabs julienbayle.net/workshop which is another page...

Comment: So it works.
I had to create template for each taxo and a page template for julienbayle.net/works with a specific loop()
. I'm still struggling with pagination problem. it throws me 404

Comment: @gluon sorry, my mistake, you need to set `has_archive` to `works`, not `true`. for your other issues, you don't need to create special templates for anything, your theme should fall back to the default. and for your pagination issues, I'll guess you're modifying the query somehow in the template, which is unnecessary. if I take the basic post and tax registration code and place it in the default twentytwelve theme, it all works as-is, no special templates, no pagination issues, no 404s, so if you're having problems with it it's something you're doing incorrectly in your templates.

Comment: @gluon - if you want to style works and worktype uniquely, you only need one template for the post type, `archive-works.php`, and a single template for worktype, `taxonomy-worktype.php`, you don't need one for each term.

Comment: thans a lot for your answers.
It worked, now it doesn't. I only added a custom field to my custom type and reflushed my permalinks (just resaved settings)
Ok about templating but where is my mistake. permalinks seems okay but produce 404 (I cannot reach my worktyped posts :(

Comment: did you maybe change the order things were registered in? I think you have to do tax first, then post type, or the rules won't be in the correct order and the wrong one will "win" resulting in 404. [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/monkeyman-rewrite-analyzer/) is handy for seeing what rules requests are matching up to, may give you a hint as to what's going wrong.

Comment: curiously, the permalink modification, saved, then remodified, then saved made the trick... weird :p

Answer (score 0):

Change your permalink and set to this

```
    %postname%/
```

Its change your url 
Like a site url/category name/postname

Comment: and I lose the julienbayle.net/blog/... for all my blog posts :(